# How to get a closed form for $\sum m f(n,m)$ where $f(n,m)$ is number of weak compositions?

Tags: combinatorics

First, consider how many $n$-dimensional vector of non-negative integers $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$ are there whose sum of all entries satisfies $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=m$?

For example for $n=2,m=2$, there are $(2,0),(1,1),(0,2)$, so $f(2,2)=3$.

For $n=3,m=2$ there are $(2,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,2),(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1)$, so $f(3,2)=6$.

How about for general $m,n$? What I know is $f(n,m)\le$ n+m choose n by [How many $k-$dimensional non-negative integer arrays $(x_1,\cdots,x_k)$ satisfies $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k\le n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2710320/how-many-k-dimensional-non-negative-integer-arrays-x-1-cdots-x-k-satisfie)

--

Then, I would like a closed form solution for $$\sum_{m=0}^Mf(n,m)$$

Comment: You can search the site for weak compositions and read [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) about bit

Comment: I changed the question, it this okay now?

Comment: This seems a strange thing to be interested in.  Where does it come from?  The sum of the first term is $\frac 12M(M+1)$.  The second is the sum of some of a row of Pascal's triangle.  I am not aware of a nice form, though you can use the normal approximation.

Comment: It comes from trying to derive algorithm complexity. How $N$ scales is more important here.

Comment: @RossMillikan made a mistake, just edited it.

Comment: We don't have any $N$ in the problem.  As $n$ gets large you should be able to put an upper bound on it based on the fact that the last term is the largest.

Comment: How about just $\sum_{m=0}^Mf(m,N)$? Should it be $m+N$ choose $N$? Is this larger than $M^2$?

Comment: You didn't look at the link I gave you.  $f(m,N)={N+m-1 \choose m-1}$.  For large $N$ it is of order $N^{m-1}$ with a constant out front.